# Ajustar a tamaño del contenedor

Tags: html, div

Buenas noches, día a día me surge un problema, siempre trato de que un objeto adapte su height o width al contenedor en el cual se encuentra (en este caso es el height)

CODIGO:

```
<header>
        <div id="HeadInicio">
            <h1 id="Selly">Texto</h1>
                <nav id="Principal">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="primerli"><a class="primeraa" href="#"><span class=""></span>Texto</a></li>
                        <li ><a class="primeraa" href="#"><span class=""></span>Texto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

En pocas palabras lo que busco es que el UL tenga la altura del DIV en el que se encuentra de forma automática y se vaya adaptando de acuerdo a la resulción, así mismo con el LI dentor del UL. Espero ser claro, desde ya muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tienes que agregarle la medida de css `vh` que quiere decir el 100% de la ventana del navegador espero te ayude saludos.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#HeadInicio {
 width:100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: rgb(207, 39, 91);
}
#HeadInicio h1 {
   position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#HeadInicio nav {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100vh;
   background:  rgb(3, 215, 224);
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div id="HeadInicio">
            <h1 id="Selly">Texto</h1>
                <nav id="Principal">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="primerli"><a class="primeraa" href="#"><span class=""></span>Texto</a></li>
                        <li ><a class="primeraa" href="#"><span class=""></span>Texto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Luis! Ya conseguí hacerlo!

Comment: Excelente amigo que bueno poder ayudarte.